# Create CATransition for UIView from current state

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation, catransition

I'm trying to make a push animation from one side using a `CATransition`.  I do this in method which handles two `UIViews`, one for the background and another for the foreground.  The animated `UIView` is be the foreground.  However I don't want the new content to replace the old one, so to do this I'm moving all the old content from the foreground to the background `UIView` expecting that it will just animate the push transition of the `UIView` from one side, but instead it replaces the old `UIView`.  Is there any way to do what I'm attempting to do, something like locking the state of the `UIViews` from the moment where the foreground and background `UIViews` have the right content?

My code is something like this:

```
UIView *newView = argView; // argView is the view passed as a parameter to the method
// move views from foreground to background
for (UIView *v in [fgView subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
    [bgView addSubview:v];
}

// Slide animation
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[fgView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[fgView addSubview:newView];
```

**[edit]** *I've been doing some research.  Apparently (or what I think might be happening) is that the background's UIViews removal are adopting implicit animation.  Is there a way to stop it from animating?*

**[edit]** *Answer: Yes, it can be done (disabling the implicit animation) and it is done with the following code*

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
for (UIView *v in [fgView subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
    [bgView addSubview:v];
}
[CATransaction commit];
```

*This is what I did and it should work (according to apple's developer portal) but it doesn't, so the question is still open.*

**[edit]** *After a lot of testing and reading I have found out that the problem is that when I remove a view from its superview the Transition or Animation does not recognizes this change until later, so it responds outdated of the latest changes.  Is there any way to force an update or to check when a `removeFromSuperview` or `addSubview` is finished?*

**[edit]** *What I need exactly is this:
1) the current state of the UIViews is: bgView with old views behind a shaded UIView or midView (this view shouldn't be animated).  A midView which is NEVER animated.  A fgView with the current UIView.
2) I want to move the contents of fgView to bgView (which won't be animated) and animate the appearance of a new UIView which is added to fgView (using Slide, Fade in/out or Flip animations).*

Comment: It seems what I am trying to do here can't be achieved.  Hmmm... who would say?

Comment: Have you tried -[UIView setNeedsDisplay] to force an update for your removeFromSuperview / addSubview calls?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not quite clear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  Is the problem that you are using the same UI element in two different views?  A UIView can only be a child of one UIView.  Also, why do you need to use a CATransition for this?  Using the UIView class methods for transitioning views is generally easier.

Comment: Yes, I temporarily solved it using a CATransition, however there are things I can't figure out to replicate with this method.  How do you make a flip animation, even the slide animation (push) is not the same if you do it with the CATransition.

Comment: So are you adding new content in the new foreground view? So this works like a page stack? Can you post a bit more code? There are variables here that we can't tell what they are or where they come from.

Comment: Yes, it is like a page stack.  It handles the bgView (with the pages behind a midView that contains only a black half opaque layer), the midView which is never animated or moved, and the fgView which contains the pages on top of the midView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the better way is to make a "screenshot" of your old content and add the screenshot as a UIImageView, then you can change your UIView's content to the new one.

After this, you can easily add animations to the two views and there is no need to worry about the old content be changed.

You can add the two files below into your project and get a UIView's screenshot by invoke `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithUIView:view]];`

As it's a UIImageView, so you don't have to worry about the content of the view will be changed.

UIImage+ImagewithUIView.h

```
@interface UIImage (UIImage+ImagewithUIView)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithUIView:(UIView *)view;
@end
```

UIImage+ImagewithUIView.m

```
@implementation UIImage (UIImage+ImagewithUIView)
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TakeScreenShot
static CGContextRef createBitmapContext(int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh)
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return bitmapContext;
}

+ (UIImage *)imageWithUIView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGSize screenShotSize = view.bounds.size;
    CGContextRef contextRef = createBitmapContext(screenShotSize.width, screenShotSize.height);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (contextRef, 0, screenShotSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(contextRef, 1, -1);

    [view.layer renderInContext:contextRef];
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(contextRef);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    // return the image
    return img;
}
@end
```

Comment: I've edited my answer and added some code. Actually this is a very easy animation, you don't need CATransition at all. UIView's animation methods is good enough.

Comment: How would you do a slide animation with UIView's animation methods? I would also need to create flip and fade in/out animations.  Also, I tried this screenshot method, the animation is still doing the same.

Comment: What is happening is this:
1) the current state of the UIViews is: bgView with old views behind a shaded UIView or midView (this view shouldn't be animated).  A midView which is NEVER animated.  A fgView with the current UIView.
2) I want to move the contents of fgView to bgView (which won't be animated) and animate the appearance of a new UIView which is added to fgView (using Slide, Fade in/out or Flip animations).

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *newView = argView; // argView is the view passed as a parameter to the method
// move views from foreground to background
[fgView.layer removeAllAnimations]; // make sure all, if any, animations are removed.
for (UIView *v in [fgView subviews]) 
{
    // [v removeFromSuperview]; // this should not be needed addSubview does it for you
    [bgView addSubview:v];
}

// Slide animation
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.removedOnCompletion = YES; // force removal of animation when completed.
[fgView addSubview:newView];
[fgView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Comment: I tried this before I separated fgView from bgView.  The purpose of having them separated is to have them separated with a UIView that is between them and that is not animated.

Comment: Why are you calling `[bgView addSubview:oldView];` in a loop? What is `oldView`?

Comment: sorry about the oldView... is is v.  I edited the sample code.

Comment: Just a thought, but try removing previous animations before altering the layer orders and creating new animations. I made an edit to my answer.